# Android layout alignment issues

Tags: android, android-layout

So I am trying to get my layout to look like this:

```
| button       text       button |
```

So that the text is centered between my two buttons. I first tried using LinearLayouts and layout_gravity tags, but that would give me something like:

```
|        buttontextbutton        |
```

and now I have a relative layout with alignParentLeft/Right and centerInParent tags but the layout now looks like

```
| button text buttonnnnnnnnnnnnn |
```

Is there a way to get my layout right with text that changes lengths?

Thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a linear layout with a horizontal orientation setting.  Remove any gravity/align settings.  Next use the line

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

in both buttons and the textview.  That should give you what you want.

Edit: You asked how it works.  This is from the [developer doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html)

> LinearLayout also supports assigning a
>   weight to individual children. This
>   attribute assigns an "importance"
>   value to a view, and allows it to
>   expand to fill any remaining space in
>   the parent view. Child views can
>   specify an integer weight value, and
>   then any remaining space in the view
>   group is assigned to children in the
>   proportion of their declared weight.
>   Default weight is zero. For example,
>   if there are three text boxes and two
>   of them declare a weight of 1, while
>   the other is given no weight (0), the
>   third text box without weight will not
>   grow and will only occupy the area
>   required by its content. The other two
>   will expand equally to fill the space
>   remaining after all three boxes are
>   measured. If the third box is then
>   given a weight of 2 (instead of 0),
>   then it is now declared "more
>   important" than both the others, so it
>   gets half the total remaining space,
>   while the first two share the rest
>   equally.

Comment: Wow.....its like magic. Only probably is that is stretching my ImageButtons slightly.

Comment: And I guess it would be helpful to know HOW this works seeing as I will probably want to use it int he future.

Comment: Awesome thanks. For future reference, I only gave the weight of 1 to the text and the buttons didn't stretch.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a LinearLayout just fine. Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView Centered"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not certain that the layout_weight attribute is even necessary in this case. You can try it with or without, but this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you try out `<TableLayout>` for this. Make sure you set `android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"` in your case.

```
<TableLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">
```